# UDP-server is up but UDP-request is not delivered (Skapy)

Tags: python, udp, scapy

I run a simple UDP-server and UDP-client on WSL2 Ununtu:

```
ak$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Here is a UDP-server code:

```py
import socket

localIP     = "127.0.0.1"
localPort   = 65002
bufferSize  = 1024
msgFromServer       = "Hello UDP Client"
bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromServer)

# Create a datagram socket
UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind to address and ip
UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))
 
print("UDP server up and listening")
while(True):

    print('Ready to get new data...')
    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(1024)
    message = bytesAddressPair[0]
    address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP  = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)
    
    UDPServerSocket.sendto(b'abc', address)
    print(clientMsg)
    print(clientIP)
```

As you can see server is running on localhost on port 65002 and simply sends "abc" to any request.
Code of the UDP-client:

```py
import socket

#msgFromClient       = "Hello UDP Server"
msgFromClient       = ""
bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromClient)
serverAddressPort   = ("127.0.0.1", 65002)
bufferSize          = 1024


# Create a UDP socket at client side
UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Send to server using created UDP socket
UDPClientSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddressPort)
msgFromServer = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
msg = "Message from Server {}".format(msgFromServer[0])
print(msg)
```

As you can see client simply sends empty data to server and print the response.
When I run this using

```
python udp_server.py
```

and

```
python udp_client.py
```

I can see the communication via tcpdump:

```
ak$ sudo tcpdump -i lo -X -s 65535 -v 'icmp or udp'
tcpdump: listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 65535 bytes
10:32:27.555794 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30437, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 28)
    localhost.41796 > localhost.65002: UDP, length 0
        0x0000:  4500 001c 76e5 4000 4011 c5e9 7f00 0001  E...v.@.@.......
        0x0010:  7f00 0001 a344 fdea 0008 fe1b            .....D......
10:32:27.555908 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30438, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 31)
    localhost.65002 > localhost.41796: UDP, length 3
        0x0000:  4500 001f 76e6 4000 4011 c5e5 7f00 0001  E...v.@.@.......
        0x0010:  7f00 0001 fdea a344 000b fe1e 6162 63    .......D....abc
```

So, everything looks OK, I see the request and the response.

But when I try to do same request via Skapy-library:

```py
>>> sr(inet.IP(dst='127.0.0.1') / inet.UDP(sport=40794, dport=65002) / Raw(), timeout=5)
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
.
Received 1 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
(<Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>, <Unanswered: TCP:0 UDP:1 ICMP:0 Other:0>)
```

I can see only the request in tcpdump, there is no any response from server:

```
ak$ sudo tcpdump -i lo -X -s 65535 -v 'icmp or udp'
tcpdump: listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 65535 bytes
10:35:26.376590 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 1, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 28)
    localhost.40794 > localhost.65002: UDP, length 0
        0x0000:  4500 001c 0001 0000 4011 7cce 7f00 0001  E.......@.|.....
        0x0010:  7f00 0001 9f5a fdea 0008 6496            .....Z....d.
```

So message is not passed to UDP-server by some reason.
Could anybody give a hint why this happens? What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!